# Tracing flash to a line which doesn't exist, flash CS5/AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I got an error on frame1:26. The code for this frame (the complete code) is below. The error message I get is is:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert 0 to flash.display.DisplayObject.
    at fl.motion::AnimatorBase/play()
    at fl.motion::AnimatorBase$/processCurrentFrame()
    at fl.motion::AnimatorBase/handleEnterFrame()
    at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
    at Lemonade_fla::MainTimeline/begin()[Lemonade_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:26]
```

If I'm reading this message correctly it says it encounters an error on a line which doesn't have any code on it. See (21 lines not 26/whatever):

```
import flash.events.Event;
stop();

var bg1_menue:Sound = new Sound();
bg1_menue.load(new URLRequest("/bg1_menu/bg1_menu.mp3"));
bg1_menue.play();

var cash1:Number = 5.00;
var maximum_storage:Number = 500;
var storage1:Number = lemons1;
var lemons1:Number = 10;
var cups:Number = 10;
var straws:Number = 100;
var ice:Number = 5;
var drinks:Number = 0;


startbt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, begin);
function begin(event:MouseEvent):void{
    nextFrame();
    }
```

**Frame 2 Code:**

```
import flash.events.Event;
stop();
stand.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, check);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, check);
function check(ev : Event) : void {
    cash.text.text = cash1;
    lemons_count.text.text = lemons1;
    cups_count.text.text = cups;
    straws_count.text.text = straws;
    ice_count.text.text = ice;


}
```

If you need, I'll supply other source code for it.

```
shop_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shopnow);
function shopnow(event:MouseEvent):void{
    nextFrame();
}

for(var i:Number = 0; i<2; i++)
{
var guide_tut:guide = new guide();
addChild(guide_tut);
}
```

Comment: might be a problem with your guide class.
post the source if it's not a sensitive proj.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

```
var storage1:Number = lemons1;
var lemons1:Number = 10;
```

This is bad, swap the two lines.

Rob

Comment: Of course you do. That was just a logical mistake I saw and pointed out :). Have you got your "startbt" instance on the first frame as well? When do you get this error? When you compile your Flash or when you click the button?

Comment: Yes, but the error keeps poping up. Even when I click dissmiss all.